# Create a new tag for Adobe Media Server

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-process

The existing tag, [flash-media-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash-media-server) refers to v4.X.X and below of the Adobe Media Server, which I'm sure many people are still using.

Since Version 5, it has been renamed to Adobe Media Server. There is no tag for this. Can someone with enough rep make one?

Here's an example of a [flash-media-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash-media-server) tagged question that should be tagged [adobe-media-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe-media-server).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582542/typeerror-error1009-existing-in-ams-version-5-only

This one specifically mentions version 5 (AMS) and explicitly differentiates it version 4.5 (FMS). His question is technically mislabeled.

Alternatively, see all of my questions under the [flash-media-server] tag, which are all for v5 and above, since I've never worked with v4.

Comment: Are there questions about it yet?

Comment: @Mat How can you tell when there's no tag? Every question I've asked under the existing tag is an Adobe Media Server question, but   I used the existing tag because it was the closest available thing

Comment: @Houseman http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Adobe+Media+Server is ~500 questions, and a [more strict version](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Adobe+Media+Server%22) is 80

Comment: @gunr2171 What's your point? That there is a tag for [adobe] and a tag for [media]?

Comment: No, that's not a tag search, that's a keyword search. I'm saying that there are 80 questions in the system with the exact phrase "Adobe Media Server", which helps your argument against Mat for "Are there questions about it yet?"

Comment: @Mat Yes, there are questions about it, besides all of mine.

Comment: @gunr2171: I'm not arguing anything. If there are already questions, fine. Just point one good one out and the tag can be created. But both your searches hit questions back to 2009, so it doesn't seem like that branding is very strong/strict so someone with a bit of knowledge will have to handle it - is there a point in keeping the "old" tag around.

Comment: @Mat Here's one  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582542/typeerror-error1009-existing-in-ams-version-5-only

Comment: @Mat, "argument" was a poor word choice. I'm just throwing out some neutral stats. So then next question for Houseman is: How useful will adding the new tag be? Will it allow experts to find questions faster? Will adding the tag disambiguate posts? I don't have enough knowledge in the subject to judge this.

Comment: @gunr2171 Do you want me to answer you directly or are you trying to help me formulate a "case" that can be presented to someone with the proper amount of rep and knowledge about the subject?

Comment: I'm trying to help you. Like I said, I don't know enough about the technology. Putting those answers in your post could certainly strengthen your case. Though from what I've seen so far the tag should be created and possibly a synonym created.

Comment: @gunr2171 Okay, thanks. I'll try to answer these questions in my edits to the original post